# Prove that circle centers are colinear

Tags: geometry, contest-math

We are given:

- circle $\omega $ on the plane,
- point $A$ in the interior of $\omega$,
- point $B\neq A$.

Consider all circles passing through the points $B$, $X$ and $Y$, where $\overline{XY}$ is any chord of $\omega$ such that $A\in \overline{XY}$.

Prove that the centers of these circles are colinear.

I attach the diagram of sample situation (with three circles):

[image]

This is supposedly not a very challenging problem, yet I struggle to find any solution. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a constant $k_A$ such that for any chord $XY$ through $A$
$$XA \cdot AY = k_A$$ Then take the point $C \in AB$ with the property that $A$ is between $B$ and $C$ such that $$CA \cdot AB = k_A$$ Then all circles you describe must pass through points $B$ and $C$. Since $BC$ is a common chord for all of them, their centers lie on the orthogonal bisector of $BC$.